# Search the nearest sprite - Andengine - Android

Tags: android, search, andengine, point

I have a trouble when I try locate the sprite more near of my player. I have a little map and side scroll. only have a grow and a player on middle. He can looks and walk  left or right, and if your player looks left and you press "shot", I search on my linkedlist of mobs a the most near Mob of my player and I do this mob receibe the damage.

I have this code:
- mobs is my linkedlist of mobs. (Extends of AnimatedSprite)

This is my first game, and I dont know if there are a better method of do this, this dont search the more near, only the first element of my list, any idea? :)

```
public void shot(){
    float playerx = player.getX();
    Mob target = mobs.element();
    if(player.getDireccion()==Entidad.DIR_IZQUIERDA){//If direction if left
        for(Mob z:mobs){
            if(z.getX()<playerx &&
               z.getX()>target.getX())
                target= z;
        }
    }else if(player.getDireccion()==Entidad.DIR_DERECHA){//If direction is right
        for(Mob z:mobs){
            if(z.getX()>playerx && z.getX()<target.getX())
                target= z;
        }
    }

    target.recibeDaño();//receibe damaget (loss life basically)

    if(objetivo.getVida()<=0){ //These delete body and sprite of the game
        final Mob eliminar = target;
        eliminarZombie(eliminar,this);
        mobs.remove(target);
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Sorry my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop over all enemies and calculate the distance which is

distance = x2 - x1

where x2 is the x attribute of the enemy and x1 is the x attribute of the player

only take into account the positive distances if you are facing right , and only take the negative distances if you are facing left

then chose the smallest absolute value of the distance

so it's something like this

```
float shortest = 1000; //just put a large number here

for(Mob z:mobs){
    distance = z.x - player.x;
    if((player.getDirection == Direction.RIGHT) && distance > 0 && distance < shortest){
        //set the target to the current mob and change the value of the shortest
    }
    if((player.getDirection == Direction.LEFT) && distance < 0 && Math.abs(distance) < shortest){
        //same as above
    }
}
//damage the target here and remove it
```

just notice that I didn't take care of the case where the target is right on top of the enemy and the distance == 0

your code should work too , but instead of looping over the list twice , it's better to loop once

other notes on your code are:

- don't call System.gc(), not a good idea
- if you want to remove an item from a linked list , remove it on updateThread using this.runOnUpdateThread() and give it a runnable [if you don't do it this way your game will crash randomly]
- you might also use an iterator to go over the items , then use .remove() to remove the latest item you reached , it's thread safe